# PuTTY: disable copy-paste on mouse selection

Tags: putty

Is there a way to make it so that simply highlighting text in PuTTY DOESN'T automatically copy that text to the clipboard?  I want to have to actually right click and select copy or type `[CRTL]+[SHIFT]+C` to copy.

I've turned off right-click pasting by going to Configuration>Window>Selection and choosing "Windows", but highlighting still copies.

Answer (score 2):

The "copy on selection" feature likely cannot be disabled.  The PuTTY manual (specifically [3.1.1 Copying and pasting text](https://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-selection)) does not specify any way to disable copy on selection.

As a workaround, consider using a different client.  I use [Cygwin](http://cygwin.org) which includes `mintty` terminal client which does have an option to disable "Copy on select."

Comment: I've been using Cygwin for 10 years and I love it.  Sadly, my new company appears to use an antivirus that conflicts with the installer.  For now, I'm stuck with PuTTY.

Comment: The line for the configuration file (`~/.minttyrc`) is `CopyOnSelect=no`.

Answer (score 1):

You can Disable copy/ paste by going to putty configuration \ windows \ selection

then change "Mouse Paste Action" to "No Action" to disable mouse paste
and then uncheck "Auto-copy selected text to system clipboard" to disable mouse copy

then save to session settings for all sessions

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Selection settings and change two settings:

- Action of mouse buttons -> from Compromise to Windows (Right click brings menu)
- Assign copy/paste selected actions to clipboards (remove checkbox mark)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

###### To disable copy on text selection:

In `PuTTY Configuration | Window | Selection`, uncheck `Auto-copy selected text to system clipboard`.

###### To disable paste on right click:

In `PuTTY Configuration | Window | Selection`, for `Action of mouse buttons`, choose `Windows (Middle extends, Right brings up menu)`.

###### To save these as default settings:

In `PuTTY Configuration | Session`, choose `Default Settings`, then click `Save`.